# Агрегат должен знать и основывать свое поведение только на своем состоянии?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, проектирование, ddd, моделирование

Может ли агрегат использовать в своем поведении(методах) состояние других агрегатов? Стоит ли давать агрегату ссылки на другие агрегаты, службы с доступом к другим агрегатам или агрегат должен знать и основывать свое поведение только на своем состоянии?

Есть ли у DDD сообщества четкое понимание по паттерну "Агрегат" по данному вопросу? Или данный вопрос не касается DDD? С другой стороны, я к примеру слышал досточно однозначное мнение сообщества, что внедрять репозиторий в агрегат не стоит. Но стоит ли внедрнять другие агрегаты и службы?

Где граница между тем, чтобы операция по смыслу принаджедащая агрегату не должна выходить на уровень служб(анемичная модель), и между тем, чтобы уменьшить зависимость и связанность агрегатов.

Если агрегат основывается только на своем состоянии и внешних зависимостей у него не должно быть, то нужно делать слой из доменных служб?
Как называть такие доменные службы?

У меня есть пример. Я намеренно выкинул все лишнее, чтобы максимально упростить. И оставил только одну операцию.
В нем я реализовал такой подход:
1. Агрегаты независимы и удовлетворяют инварианты только на основе своего состояния.
2. Логика принадлежащая предметной области, но взаимодействуюшая с другими агрегатами и службами вынесена в доменные службы.

Описание примера:
Это контекст аукциона. Здесь есть Lot(Лот), Bid(Ставка на конерктный лот), Bidder(Участник аукциона - ставит ставки), Timer(Таймеры, которые ставятся либо перезапускаются для отсчета перед победой). Операция которая тут рассматривается это "сделать ставку", и вот что происходит у меня:

1. Application слой получает от клиента необходимые данные, получает на основе этих данных нужные агрегаты, службы, репозитории. Далее вызывает доменную службу (#Domain Service# BidMaker -> makeBid) и передает этой службе все необходимое.
2. Метод доменной службы (#Domain Service# BidMaker -> makeBid)

   а) Вызывает метод агрегата (#AR# Lot -> makeBid), он в свою очередь проверяет инварианты, далее создает ставку(Bid) и кладет ее к себе в bidIds

   б) Проверяет существуют ли уже таймеры у (Lot)Лота, если нет запускает новые или перезапускает старые с помощью доменной службы - WinnerTimer.

   в) Если таймеры новые сохраняет их с помощью репозитория

   г) Вызывает метод агрегата (#AR# Lot -> restartTimers), он в свою очередь кладет таймеры к себе в winnerTimerId и winnerTimerBefore2HoursId.

У меня получилось дублирование названия методов доменной службы и агрегата. И по логике все же операция "сделать ставку" принадлежит агрегату Lot(Лота). Но тогда нужно перенести логику из доменной службы BidMaker в агрегат, а это означает, что в том числе нужно будет внедрить в агрегат репозиторий таймеров и службу таймеров.

Хотелось бы услышать мнения - чтобы вы изменили в данном примере и почему? А также мнения по первому и главному вопросу. 
Заранее всех благодарю за ответы.

```
#Domain Service# 
BidMaker{
  void makeBid(
    WinnerTimer winnerTimer,
    TimerRepository timerRepository,
    int amount,
    Bidder bidder,
    Lot lot,
  ){
    //call lot.makeBid
    //check Lot's timers and put new or restart existing through WinnerTimer
    //save timers if they new through TimerRepository
    //call lot.restartTimers
  }
}

#Domain Service# 
WinnerTimer{
  Timer putWinnerTimer(){}
  Timer putWinnerTimerBefore2Hours(){}
  void restartWinnerTimer(Timer timerForRestart){}
  void restartWinnerTimerBefore2Hours(Timer timerForRestart){}
}


#AR# 
Lot{

  Lot{
    LotId id;
    BidId[] bidIds;
    TimerId winnerTimerId;
    TimerId winnerTimerBefore2HoursId;

    void makeBid(
      int amount,
      BidderId bidder,
      TimerId winnerTimerId,
      TimerId winnerTimerBefore2HoursId
    ){
      //check business invariants of #AR# within the boundaries
      //make Bid and add to bidIds
    }

    void restartTimers(TimerId winnerTimerId, TimerId winnerTimerBefore2Hours){
      //restart timers
    }
  }

  Bid{
    BidId id;
    int amount;
    BidderId bidderId;
  }

}

#AR# 
Timer{
  Timer{
    TimerId id;
    Date: date;
  }
}

#AR# 
Bidder{
  Bidder{
    BidderId: id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Агрегат может в себе содержать ссылки на другие агрегаты. А всё, что в себе содержит, может использовать для поведения. Я честно не дочитал вопрос, но по моему вопрос именно на эту тему.

Comment: @Monk Это понятно. Вопрос в другом! Может ли агрегат использовать состояние других агрегатов и основываться на них? Вернее я бы хотел услышать стоит ли так делать или почему не стоит. А также я привел пример проблем и дальнейших вопросов зависимых от основного вопроса. Я к примеру видел варианты реализации DDD, когда на вход методу одного агрегата, подают другие агрегаты, с которыми он взаимодействует(читает их состояние).

Comment: На все вопросы - да. Агрегат - это просто крупная предметная штуковина, которая в базе всегда должна быть согласована. Всё остальное в принципе не ограничено. Вы не должны особенно задумываться над DDD, работать надо с предметной областью и в её терминах.

Answer (score 4):

> У меня получилось дублирование названия методов доменной службы и агрегата. И по логике все же операция "сделать ставку" принадлежит агрегату Lot(Лота). Но тогда нужно перенести логику из доменной службы BidMaker в агрегат, а это означает, что в том числе нужно будет внедрить в агрегат репозиторий таймеров и службу таймеров.

Ваше решение вполне корректное. Можно сказать, что операция "сделать ставку" реализована на двух уровнях детализации, поэтому, по сути, это две разные операции с одинаковым названием. Может быть имеет смысл уточнить терминологию.

Далее напишу про взаимосвязь *Агрегатов*, *Репозиториев* и *Служб*, надеюсь, это поможет уложить в голове некоторые аспекты.

Если бы оперативная память не теряла своего содержимого при перезагрузке, если бы она была большой и могла хранить всю базу целиком, то *Агрегатов* и *Репозиториев* в DDD не было бы вовсе. Мы могли бы взять объект предметной области и по ссылкам выйти на любой другой объект.

Но оперативная память ненадёжна и невелика, поэтому мы вынуждены хранить объекты в базах данных. Как правило, все наши сущности соответствуют таблицам в базе данных. Проблема заключается в том, что уровень хранения зачастую слишком детален для предметной области: загрузив `Лот` мы отдельно должны загрузить `Ставки`, но если `Лот` и `Ставки` всегда нужны вместе, мы постоянно будем писать лишний код. Сюда накладываются проблемы атомарности операций: между двумя загрузками может случиться какая-нибудь вставка, и чтобы гарантировать согласованность, нам в явном виде нужно привносить в бизнес-логику *транзакции*.

*Агрегаты* как раз решают эту проблему. Заметив, что некоторые сущности почти всегда нужны вместе, мы их объединяем. На практике, одна из сущностей становится главной, так называем *Корнем агрегата*, а остальные сущности доступны как вложенные свойства. Например, `Ставки` могут быть коллекцией сущностей типа `Bid`.

Все сущности *Агрегата* загружаются из базы данных целиком в рамках одной транзакции, и точно также, все сущности *Агрегата* обновляются в базе в рамках одной транзакции.

В соответствии с *принципом единственной ответственности* (SRP), *Агрегат* решает свою основную задачу в рамках предметной области, загрузка и обновление *Агрегата* должна быть вынесена в отдельный класс. Этот класс — *Репозиторий*.

Очень важный момент заключается в том, как *Репозитории* взаимосвязаны с *Сущностями* и *Агрегатами*. *Репозиторий* знает про все сущности *Агрегата*: он создаёт их при загрузке из базы, а также извлекает из них данные для сохранения в базе. Но вот сам *Агрегат* про *Репозиторий* знать не должен.

Обсудим эту часть подробнее.

С *Агрегатами* у нас возникает проблема определения границ этих самых *Агрегатов*. Например, `Участники` делают `Ставки`, но `Участники` довольно часто возникают в сценариях и без `Ставок`. Это означает, что `Участники` – отдельный *Агрегат*.

Но если это отдельный *Агрегат* у него должен быть свой *Репозиторий* и загружаться он тоже должен отдельно. Как же быть, если нам нужен в рамках одного сценария и `Лот` со `Ставками`, и `Участник`?

Здесь нам на помощью приходят *Службы*. Чем они отличаются от *Агрегатов* и как мы можем понять, что является ответственностью *Службы*, а что — ответственностью *Агрегата*?

Важнейшим отличием является наличие состояния, у *Агрегата* оно есть, у *Службы* нет. По сути, любая операция с *Агрегатом* является операцией чтения или изменения состояния. А вот *Службы* представляют процессы, поэтому каждая операция сервиса обычно соответствует шагу процесса.

Наконец, *Агрегат* управляет только своими сущностями, а *Служба* управляет *Агрегатами*.

Теперь мы готовы объединить всё вместе.

1. *Агрегаты* не могут содержать друг друга, вместо этого ссылаются друг на друга через идентификаторы. Например, Лот содержит Ставки, и каждая Ставка хранит Идентификатор Участника.
2. Загрузку и сохранение *Агрегатов* осуществляют *Репозитории*. Здесь тонкий момент, про который надо помнить: *Агрегатор* ничего не должен знать про базы данных, а *Репозиторий* — про бизнес-логику.
3. *Службы* выполняют бизнес-процессы. Они используют *Репозитории* чтобы загружать *Агрегаты*, выполняют отдельные операции *Агрегатов*, и снова используют *Репозитории*, чтобы сохранить новые состояния *Агрегатов*.

Если в вашем коде вас волнует то, что методы одинаково называются в *Службе* и *Агрегате*, поговорите с экспертами предметной области, уточните процесс и термины. Речь здесь идёт о сложной составной операции, поэтому вполне может быть, для отдельных этапов есть свои обозначения и названия. Скажем, может быть явно как-то обозначаются новые `Ставки` без запущенных `Таймеров`. Тогда метод *Агрегата* `Лот` должен называться не `makeBid`, а как-то по другому, что-то вроде `initiateBid`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Для меня правда много лишней информации, о которой я уже осведомлен, но думаю другим целостная картина может быть полезно. У меня же вопрос был более узким. И я все же не уловил ответ на него и какие-то доводы. Все-таки вы считаете, что Агрегаты должны основывать свои действия и менять свое состояние только на основе клиентских и своих внутренних данных(внутри границы Агрегата)?

Comment: Как вы относитесь к тому, чтобы передать в Агрегат службу? К примеру Агрегат Lot сделает какие то действия, затем запустит службу запуска таймеров, эта служба запустит таймер сохранит его, а Агрегату обратно передаст индентификатор таймера, который Агрегат Lot сможет сохранить. Тут агрегат независим от других агрегатов напрямую, тк не получает прямых ссылок на них, но зависим от службы и косвенно зависим от состояния других агрегатов. Как вы считаете такой вариант допустим и почему да или почему нет?

Comment: @YuryGolikov, простой ответ: Агрегаты должны основывать свои действия только на основании клиентских и своих внутренних данных. Сложный ответ: Агрегаты, находясь на уровне предметной области, могут знать о Службах уровня инфраструктуры, но не должны знать о Службах предметного или прикладного уровней. Вот тут я не разбираюсь в вашей предметной области, и не знаю, таймеры — объекты уровня домена или уровня инфраструктуры?

Comment: Таймер у меня Агрегат, те объект предметной области. Почему вы считаете, что Агрегат не может знать о службах предметной области(доменных сервисах)? Мне интересно именно ваше обоснование. К примеру Вон Вернон в IDDD описывает возможность передачи службы предметной области в агрегат. + Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на ответ англоязычного коллеги. Можете ли вы привести примеры за или против его мнения. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753747/251196

Comment: @YuryGolikov, я этот вывод сделал, читая Эванса. На мой взгляд, он очень логично описывает артефакты: в начале вводит понятия сущностей и объектов-значений, затем — службы, всё это на основе противопоставления. То есть службы позволяют сделать что-то такое, что не позволяют делать сущности. Сущности не должны являться анемичным моделями, то есть они должны работать, опираясь на собственное состояние. Но если несколько сущностей участвуют во взаимодействии — в какую из них поместить метод? Эванс говорит: выносите метод в службу, служба нужна, чтобы выполнять операции над несколькими сущностями.

Comment: Да читал про это у Эванса. И в теории мне понравилось как звучит. Но я столкнулся тут с практической частью. И у меня получается, что если я выношу службу предметной области НАД агрегатами, то у агрегат становится несколько анемичным и не выражает в полной мере свои действия. Поэтому у меня и появился в том числе и этот вопрос: Стоит ли передавать службу в агрегат, чтобы агрегат не терял свою часть логики и не стал анемичным.

Answer (score 2):

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500729/the-aggregate-must-know-and-base-its-behavior-only-on-its-own-state-can-the-agg) участника [VoiceOfUnreason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54734/voiceofunreason). С англоязычного [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com):

> агрегат должен знать и основывать свое поведение только на своем состоянии?

На своем состоянии + переданные аргументы, во время команды агрегату - измени свое состояние.

Тк агрегаты описывают границу согласованности, не стоит пытаться объединить вместе два состояния разных агрегатов. Но нет ничего неправильного в том, чтобы обновлять один агрегат используя снимок(snapshot) другого агрегата как аргумент.

Лично я обычно не использую сам агрегат для этого. Я думаю метод с двумя агрегатами может сбить с толку, тк нет прозрачного понимания - какой конкретно агрегат сейчас меняется. Но read-only агрегат вполне подходит для этого.

Лучшее решение может быть использование доменной службы как посредника. Поэтому методы которые изменяют состояние Лота - никогда не смогут изменить состояние Таймера, и никогда не будут взаимодействовать с Таймером напрямую. Но Лот может спросить службу предметной области о состоянии Таймера, передав ей id Таймер, который интересен.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, агрегат. Он блюдёт своё собственное состояние и обеспечивает его консистентность. Для этого требуется сложная (как правило) бизнес-логика: проверка инвариантов, валидация и прочее. Представим себе, что мы хотим эту логику протестировать. Какие у нас тут варианты?

Тестировать удобнее всего чистые функции. Потому что результат выполнения чистой функции детерминирован. Поэтому ОЧЕНЬ УДОБНО, когда команды агрегата реализованы в виде чистой функции. Функция на вход получает текущее состояние агрегата и команду, возвращает (выберите по вкусу) (новое состояние агрегата | сообщение об ошибке) или (событие об изменении состояния агрегата | сообщение об ошибке).

Это легко протестировать, но что делать с зависимостями? Для того, чтобы логика агрегата была чистой, у него не должно быть зависимостей. То есть, все зависимости необходимо разрешить до отправки команды агрегату и предоставить ему все необходимые данные.

Я не знаю, как правильно назвать часть кода, ответственную за получение данных от зависимостей. Можно назвать domain service. Можно use case. В моём коде это сложено в package под названием businesslogic. Идея в том, что там в одном куске кода описан целиком use case, и его выполнение увенчивается отправкой команды агрегату.

Далее, в коде модели предметной области также присутствуют package-и downstream (интерфейсы взаимодействия с теми, кто от меня зависит - они делегируют выполнение методам юз-кейсов) и upstream (интерфейсы взаимодействия с теми, от кого завишу я, они передаются юз-кейсам в качестве аргументов конструктора).

(Также может помочь знакомство с концепцией Data-Context-Interaction от Trygve Reenskaug).

Таким образом, экземпляр use-case-а - вот кто нуждается в зависимостях. Но интерфейсы этих зависимостей я имплементирую в другом модуле, в модуле адаптеров. А в модуле, содержащем предметную область, я их только объявляю. Чтобы предметная область не зависела от реализаций ни downstream, ни upstream адаптеров.

Может быть небольшая путаница в терминологии, но у себя я Application-ом называю ту часть кода, в которой связываются три части: конфигурация, предметная область и интерфейсы адаптеров с конкретными имплементациями. В частности, там создаются экземпляры юз-кейсов (часть предметной области) с переданными их конструкторам адаптерами.

Далее, клиентский код у application-а берёт эти экземпляры юз-кейсов и вызывает их методы. Юз-кейсы, используя upstream-адаптеры, получают необходимые данные и с этими данными формируют команды для агрегатов. Когда агрегаты выполняют свою задачу, юз-кейсы, снова используя адаптеры, выполняют запись в БД/на диск или отправку в MQ и т.д.

Если мы потом договоримся о терминологии - я поправлю ответ. Сейчас получается. так:

Application создаёт экземпляры адаптеров и юз-кейсов, внедряя в них экземпляры адаптеров.
Клиентский запрос парсится в downstream-адаптере таким образом, чтобы оказаться выраженным в через value-object-ы предметной области. Если не получилось распарсить - возвращаем bad request, даже не доходя до отработки юз-кейса. Если получилось - вызываем метод юз-кейса makeBid. В рамках этого метода используем адаптеры и получаем текущее значение таймера, необходимые атрибуты Bidder-а, агрегат Lot в текущем состоянии. Формируем команду для Lot-а и отправляем ему. Он отрабатывает свою чистую логику и возвращает новое состояние, или событие, или ошибку. Юз-кейс дёргает адаптеры снова и сохраняет успешный ответ от Lot-a. Результат возвращается обратно downstream-адаптеру, где формируется ответ клиенту.

Итог: агрегаты содержат чистую логику, которую мы можем удобно покрыть тестами. Юз-кейс содержит полную картину взаимодействия с upstream-адаптерами и выражает порадок и зависимости операций друг от друга. То есть, координирует их. Здесь нет формул, нет инвариантов - есть только порядок, последовательность, зависимости. Соответственно, только это и тестируем. Адаптеры сфокусированы каждый на своём отдельном канале взаимодействия с внешним миром. Со стороны домена у адаптеров статические структуры данных, чтобы сосредоточить тестирование только на взаимодействии с этим внешним миром. Application просто связывает всё это + конфигурацию друг с другом. Непонятно, что там тестировать, как и надо ли.

Комментируйте, если я что-то непонятно изложил.